# Careers pdf export cannot include "Writing" section plus unticking "Tools" doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

There are two issues I've come across in the Careers PDF export that I'm not sure if anyone else has reported yet:

1. It seems it is not possible to include items from the "Writing" section in the output PDF.  In my case, I have a few journal/conference articles I would like included in the PDF that I'm unable to due to this.
2. Unticking "Tools" in the CV Preview seems to hide tools from the preview, but when one actually presses the "Export to PDF" button, the output PDF still includes the Tools section.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done!

As of right now, you can include the Writing section in the PDF, and the Tools toggle now works properly.